# Issue with using \onecolumn with ReVTeX

Tags: appendices, columns, revtex

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm trying to switch from double column to single column in a report I am working on. The single column is for the appendices. I've been trying to use the `\onecolumn` command, but I get the error: `Undefined control sequence`. Am I missing a package or something? I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I am using the template from this link https://www.overleaf.com/read/tkvxddggwwbh at the behest of my TA.

edit: I accidentally typed `\oneline` instead of `\onecolumn`

Here is a an example:

```
\documentclass[
  reprint
]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\onecolumn
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The command to switch to one column is `\onecolumn`, not `\oneline`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I mistyped. `\onecolumn` is what I meant. I also added an example. The error also occurs when the `\documentclass` option `reprint` is changed to `twocolumn`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`revtex` disables `\onecolumn` use `\onecolumngrid`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!